# Computing $\lim_{x\to 0}[(\sin x)^{\frac{1}{x}}+(\frac{1}{x})^{\sin x}]$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can we compute the following: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[(\sin x)^{\frac{1}{x}}+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin x}\right]?$$

The expression looks rather daunting. If $x\to 0$, then $\sin x\to 0$ but $\frac{1}{x}\to \infty$ and that gives no information. Somehow, $\sin x$ seems to be nearly equal to $x$ when $x\to0$ (I am skeptical about this result) and if that is true, $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\frac{1}{x}}=1$. Can anyone please suggest how to carry out this calculation?

Comment: You should pass to the exponential form, for a start.

Comment: About $\sin x$, you can give that a precise meaning. It is "equivalent" to $x$ when $x$ approaches $0$. That is $\lim_0\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ or, equivalently, $\sin x=x+o(x)$. And if needed, you can go further in the expansion by Taylor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of the first term is not an "indeterminate power", but simply "$0^{\infty}$" $  = 0$.

For the second, L'Hopital's Rule for indeterminate powers   will be helpful:

$$ \ln [\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} (\frac{1}{x})^{\sin x}]  = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \sin x \cdot \ln(\frac{1}{x})  =   \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\ln(\frac{1}{x})}{(\frac{1}{\sin x})}  $$

$$=   \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{[\ln(\frac{1}{x})]'}{(\csc x)'} =    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{x \cdot \frac{-1}{x^2} }{-\csc x \cot x} =  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{\sin x \tan x}{ x}   $$

$$=  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}(\frac{\sin x }{ x} )\cdot \tan x  =  1 \cdot 0  =  0  .  $$

So we have  $ \ln [\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} (\frac{1}{x})^{\sin x}]  = 0  \Rightarrow  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} (\frac{1}{x})^{\sin x}  =  1$
.

The sum of the limits of the two terms is thus  $1$ .

Answer (score 4):

As a door-opener, you may know that $\sqrt[n]n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. If $x=\frac1n$, then for sufficiently big $n$, we have $\sin x\approx x=\frac1n$ and hence $(\sin x)^{\frac1x}\approx \frac1{n^n}\to 0$ and $\left(\frac1x\right)^{\sin x}\approx n^{\frac1n}\to 1$. To make this precise, something as simple as $\frac12x<\sin x<x$ and $\forall x>0\colon\exists n\colon \frac1{n+1}\le x\le\frac1n$ should be enough.

Beware however, that this treats only positive $x$. For negative $x$, on the other hand, you may even have trouble just *defining* the expressions. So all in all
$$ \lim_{x\to0^+}\left[(\sin x)^{\frac1x}+\left(\frac1x\right)^{\sin x}\right]=1.$$